# Ajax post - POST array is returning empty on server side

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an js function that is collecting data and sending it to a php file.

I am trying to submit an array as part of the post:

function send_registration_data(){

```
var string = "{username : " + $('#username').val() + ", password : " + $('#pass1').val() + ", level : " + $("#userrole").val() + ", 'property[]' : [";
var c = 0;
$('input[name=property]:checked').each(function(){
    if( c == 0){
        string +="\"" +this.value+"\"";
        c=1;
    } else {
        string +=",\""+this.value+"\"";
    }
});
string+="]}";
$('#input').html( JSON.stringify(eval("(" + string + ")")) );

$.ajax({ url: './php/submit_registration.php',
         //data: { username : $('#username').val() , password : $('#pass1').val() , email : $('#email').val() , level : $("#userrole").val() },
         data: JSON.stringify(eval("(" + string + ")")) ,
         type: 'post',
         success: function(output) {
                  $('#output').html( output );

            }
});
};
```

On submit my php file returns an the POST array as NULL. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

EDIT: IT is the same weather I try to convert the string to json or not.

ALso, the inputs contain just text names.

Comment: Is all this wrapped in a form element? If so, you can serialize the form - `data: $('form').serialize()`

Comment: When I was not using the conversion of json string to json it was doing the same thing.

Comment: @NaNpx Yes, let me try this.

Comment: Have you examined the string you produce to see that it doesn't include anything that is causing an error?

Comment: you definitely do not want to stringify it. What you want is what you originally had, the commented out part. If that isn't working, the problem is likely on the php side.

Comment: Serializing the form data did send it properly, but I'm using checkboxes with same name in the form and it only sends the last one of the checked ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**string keyword**

Do not use the "string" keyword.

**eval**

Eval is evil - use it with caution.

**strict mode**

Make sure always to work in the "strict mode" by placing this line at the beginning of your code:

```
'use strict'
```

**Building your response object**

You do not have to glue your post object manually. Just do it this way:

```
var post = {
    'username': $('#username').val(),
    'password': $('#password').val(),
    'myArray[]': ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
};
```

**jQuery the right way**

Avoid messing up with unnecessary syntax.

```
$.post(url, post)
    .done(function(response){
        // your callback
    });
```

**Conclusion**

```
'use strict'
var url = './php/submit_registration.php'; // try to use an absolute url
var properties = {};
$('input[name="property"]:checked').each(function() {
    properties.push(this.value);
});
var data = {
    'username':   $('#username').val(),
    'password':   $('#pass1').val(),
    'level':      $('#userrole').val(),
    'property[]': properties
};

// submitting this way
$.post(url, data)
    .done(function(response) {
        // continue
    })
    .fail(function(response) {
        // handle error
    });

// or this way
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(data), // you'll have to change "property[]" to "property"
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) { 
        // continue
    }
});
```

Comment: The $_POST array will still be null in this case if the input is not taken from php://input on the server side

Comment: @user602525 yeah.. he could json encode the array part of the package. Or encode it all.

Comment: I agree with your whole post of how to send up the data. But the real problem here with the $_POST array being NULL is simply, that he was trying to read from the $_POST array with json data. That doesn't work. He's gotta either use 'php://input' or $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA

Comment: @user602525 you're right, but he didn't specified any server side code - so it's guessing. I'm 99% sure what you're saying is the actual problem - but I can't prove it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get from php://input if you are not using multipart/form-data, so, application/json

```
$myData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$decoded = json_decode($myData);
```

If you're sending this up as json, your $_POST variable will continue to be NULL unless you do this.